# JS .fadeOut not fading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to get the image to fade out slower but it appears to just fade instantly, I'm then left with white space while the new image loads.

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
   <!--<img src="images/me.jpg" alt="" /> -->
   <img src="images/boatResized.jpg" alt="" />
   <img src="images/carResized.jpg" alt="" />
   <img src="images/dennis_stockRezied1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(4500)
        .next('img')
        .fadeIn(5500)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 8000); // 8 seconds
```

Im fairly new to JS and having trouble getting this to function correctly.

Comment: The `.fadeIn()` won't wait until the `.fadeOut()` is finished because they are running on different elements (and so belong to different animation queues). Put the `.fadeIn()` in the complete callback of the `.fadeOut()`.

Comment: Sorry so add .fadeOut(4500, '.fadeIn')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your call to `.fadeIn()` does not wait for the `.fadeOut()` to complete because they are called on different elements (and so belong to different animation queues). You could add a completion callback function as a second argument to `.fadeOut()` and then do the `.fadeIn()` within that function.

Note also that you are using an 8 second interval, but your fades are 4.5 and 5.5 seconds, which adds up to a 10 second turnaround. So in the following code I've increased the interval to 11. I tried to do this with as few changes to your code as possible:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(4500, function() {
        $(this).next('img')
               .fadeIn(5500)
               .end()
               .appendTo('.fadein');
    });
}, 11000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qh03e16s/

You could also get rid of the `setInterval()`, and instead trigger each fade sequence from the completion callback of the `.fadeIn()`. Then you don't have to worry about timing the interval to add up to the fade out and in, although it means the first fade begins immediately:

```
(function doFade() {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(4500, function() {
        $(this).next('img')
               .fadeIn(5500, doFade)  // note the doFade reference
               .end()
               .appendTo('.fadein');
    });
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qh03e16s/1/